# Failed at the core-js postinstall script error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am facing the following errors when I try to install node modules in an existing `Angular project`. I am trying to install the node modules in windows machine(Win32 X64).

```
       > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js 
       > node -e "try{require('-/postinstall')}catch(e){}"

      npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\ng-cli-pug-loader\node_modules\fsevents):
      npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted ("os":"darwin","arch":"any") (current: {"as":"vin3 
      npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents): arch":"x64"})

      npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted ("os": "darwin","arch":"any") (current: {"as":"u ","arch":"x64"}) 
      npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents): 
      npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted ("os": "darwin","arch":"any") (current: {"as":"win32","arch":"x64"})

      npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

      npm ERR! syscall spawn bash

      npm ERR! file bash

      npm ERR! path bash

      npm ERR! errno -4058

      npm ERR! core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: "node -e "try(require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

      npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT

      npm ERR!

      npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@3.6.4 postinstall script.

      npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

      npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

      npm ERR!

      C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-23T16_43_06_961Z-debug.log
```

The following are the versions installed in my system

```
  AngularCli : 8.3.29
  Node : 14.17.1
  NPM: 8.2.12
```

I have tried deleting node modules folder and running `npm cache clean --force` and reinstalling node modules , also tried uninstalling nodejs and deleting the npm-cache folder and reinstalling again.

Still I am facing the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the whole error. This is just one line which doesn't show the problem.

Comment: @LoganDevine Updated the error message

Comment: Does it really say "ENDENT" or does it say "ENOENT"? Is this Linux or macOS or Windows?

Comment: Hi @LoganDevine , I have corrected it . It is `ENOENT` . I am using windows 10 machine 64 bit

Comment: So it appears it's assuming you are on Linux as it tries to spawn bash. Is there *anything* weird about your version? Is your architecture "x64" or "x86_64"?

Comment: @LoganDevine , My windows system type is: 64-bit operating system, x64 based processor. I have cloned the repo from bitbucket and run npm install . My other teammates having same configuration it is working fine for them.

Comment: Try it from Git Bash.

Comment: @LoganDevine It worked using gitbash. Thankyou

Comment: I'll post that as an answer, please accept it.

Comment: Would you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the postinstall script is `fork`-and-`exec`'ing `bash`, which is not present on Windows. You need to run this from a Bash emulator like MINGW64 (Git Bash).