# Can not run npm in visual studio code on windows 10; Its show some error

Tags: node.js, npm

when I tried to run npm it showed some errors, which I maintained below. How can I solve this?

```
npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! core-js@3.6.4 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@3.6.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: What's the relevant portion of the referenced log?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105687/failed-at-the-core-js-postinstall-script-error, Which suggests bash is missing.